# How to make Cognos talk to an external website to fetch information from it?

Tags: javascript, json, report, cognos

I'm trying to get Cognos to talk to an external website and show that information within its report.

Essentially what i want is if that external website displays "true" then cognos report should display a tick, if its "false" then it shouldn't display anything.

I'm attaching how that external website looks like below. Maybe some JavaScript expert can help me with this.

[Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KscDx.png)

Comment: Do you have the website URL stored within a DB column and is this column accessible from your model?

Comment: Web site or web **service**?

Comment: @RanAvnon -- It is not stored in the DB column and is not accessible from the model.

Comment: @Andrew -- I believe its a web service. It's basically just a link that would tell us if there are notes for a certain fund or not.

Comment: Any help will be appreciated guys!!

Answer (score 0):

That depends, in part, on how the report will be viewed. If it is anything but HTML output, then you'll be limited to a solution involving either the Cognos SDK or Framework Manager to bring in WSDL data sources.

With HTML output, you can use javascript or html includes or iframes: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_html_include_1

Javascript may be problematic depending on the site because you could get into cross-domain scripting limitations.